# Error in archiving : clang: error: no such file or directory /Release-iphoneos/file.a

Tags: ios, xcode

Running an iOS App archive in Xcode, I'm getting the below error. The app runs fine on an iOS device and on the simulator but fails when archiving. The file that it can't find (libAppEngine iOS.a) is my native C++ library compiled by Xcode.

My native library seems to archive without errors when done alone.

I'm using Xcode 9.2. I've deleted my derived data, restarted Xcode, checked that there are no missing files in either project, deleted and readded the native file. Any solutions on how to solve this problem?

> Ld
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App\
>   Next normal arm64
>       cd /Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Libraries/Unity/Libraries/Plugins/iOS
>   -L/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Libraries/Unity/Libraries -L/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AFNetworking
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Bolts
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CocoaAsyncSocket
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/CorePlot
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKShareKit
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookCore
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookLogin
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FacebookShare
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMOAuth2
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/JGActionSheet
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MarqueeLabel
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Mixpanel
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SBJson
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SDWebImage
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Socket.IO-Client-Swift
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/SocketRocket
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/StarscreamSocketIO
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Toaster
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XMLDictionary
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/hpple
>   -F/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/objective-zip
>   -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/Google/Frameworks -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds
>   -F/Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks -filelist /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App\
>   Next.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App\
>   Next_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker
>   -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -final_output -Xlinker /Applications/App\ Next.app/App\ Next -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App_Module.swiftmodule
>   -lc++ -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -ObjC -ObjC -lGoogleAnalytics -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AFNetworking -framework AVFoundation -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework Bolts -framework CocoaAsyncSocket -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation
>   -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CorePlot -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework Crashlytics -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework Fabric -framework
>   FacebookCore -framework FacebookLogin -framework FacebookShare
>   -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GGLCore -framework GGLSignIn -framework
>   GLKit -framework GTMOAuth2 -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework
>   GoogleInteractiveMediaAds -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework
>   GoogleSignIn -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework JGActionSheet
>   -framework MarqueeLabel -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework Mixpanel -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SBJson -framework SDWebImage -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework SocketIO -framework SocketRocket -framework StarscreamSocketIO -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Toaster -framework
>   UIKit -framework UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints -framework XMLDictionary
>   -framework hpple -framework objective_zip -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -framework ContactsUI -framework StoreKit -licucore -lsqlite3 -lxml2 -lz -liconv -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -liPhone-lib -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo
>   -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework iAd -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer
>   -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework ImageIO -framework MapKit -framework Pods_App
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libAppEngine\
>   iOS.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App\
>   Next_dependency_info.dat -o
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Objects-normal/arm64/App\
>   Next
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libAppEngine
>   iOS.a'
>
> (null): error: cannot parse the debug map for
>   "/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App
>   Next.app/App Next": No such file or directory
>
> GenerateDSYMFile
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/App\
>   Next.app.dSYM
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App\
>   Next.app/App\ Next
>       cd /Users/x/Projects/GIT/App-iPhone
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App\
>   Next.app/App\ Next -o
>   /Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/App\
>   Next.app.dSYM
>
> error: cannot parse the debug map for
>   "/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App
>   Next.app/App Next": No such file or directory

Some reason the library is being put in the wrong folder it seems. 
It’s looking at the folder: /Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppProd/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libAppEngine\ iOS.a

When it should be: /⁨Users/jess/⁨Library⁩/⁨Developer⁩/⁨Xcode⁩/⁨DerivedData/⁨App-dmjqadgxdcinrrcgwugqdedztquy/⁨Build⁩/⁨Intermediates.noindex⁩/⁨ArchiveIntermediates/⁨AppEngine iOS⁩/⁨BuildProductsPath⁩/libAppEngine\ iOS.a